# time tracker with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I have so far is a table where a user can input their hours,minutes,activity name, and the category of that activity. A user can add/delete rows as they see fit.

What I need to accomplish is, when the user clicks the "Calculate" button it will add the hours/minutes and then store the input value in "activity" and "category".

Here is a Fiddle of what I have so far.  http://jsfiddle.net/os214gru/

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>English Styles Test</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.17.2/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css">
        <link href="http://explore.hawkeslearning.com/portal/content/css/learn_content_styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/form-styles.css" rel="stylesheet">



        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    // if Google is down, it looks to local file...
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
      document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/clone-form-td.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ 
http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-modal-tutorial/ -->
<div id="screenContainer">
    <div id="screenContainerEng">

    <div class='budgetForm-ENG'>
        <form action="#" method="post" id="BudgetFormEng">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan='4'>Time Budget Calculator</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th id='hourLabel'>Hour</th>
                        <th id='minuteLabel'>Minutes</th>
                        <th id='activityLabel'>Activity</th>
                        <th id='categoryLabel'>Category</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="CloneRow">
                        <td>
                            <input class="input_hr" type="number" value="0" name="ID_hour" id="ID_hour" aria-labeledby="hourLabel" min="0">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="input_min" type="number" value="0" name="ID_min" id="ID_min" min="0" max="59" aria-labeledby="minuteLabel">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="ID_act" id="ID_act" aria-labeledby="activityLabel">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="input_cat" name="ID_cat" id="ID_cat" aria-labeledby="cateogryLabel">
                                <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disbled">
                                    Select Category
                                </option>

                                <option value="Class">
                                    Class
                                </option>

                                <option value="Entertainment">
                                    Entertainment
                                </option>

                                <option value="Exercise">
                                    Exercise
                                </option>

                                <option value="Extracurricular">
                                    Extracurricular
                                </option>

                                <option value="Family">
                                    Family
                                </option>

                                <option value="Meal">
                                    Meal
                                </option>

                                <option value="Other">
                                    Other
                                </option>

                                <option value="Personal">
                                    Personal
                                </option>

                                <option value="Sleep">
                                    Sleep
                                </option>

                                <option value="Social">
                                    Social
                                </option>

                                <option value="Study">
                                    Study
                                </option>

                                <option value="Work">
                                    Work
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="CloneRow0">
                        <td>
                            <input class="input_hr" type="number" value="0" name="ID0_hour" id="ID0_hour" aria-labeledby="hourLabel" min="0">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="input_min" type="number" value="0" name="ID0_min" id="ID0_min" min="0" max="59" aria-labeledby="minuteLabel">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="ID0_act" id="ID0_act" aria-labeledby="activityLabel">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="input_cat" name="ID0_cat" id="ID0_cat" aria-labeledby="cateogryLabel">
                                <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disbled">
                                    Select Category
                                </option>

                                <option value="Class">
                                    Class
                                </option>

                                <option value="Entertainment">
                                    Entertainment
                                </option>

                                <option value="Exercise">
                                    Exercise
                                </option>

                                <option value="Extracurricular">
                                    Extracurricular
                                </option>

                                <option value="Family">
                                    Family
                                </option>

                                <option value="Meal">
                                    Meal
                                </option>

                                <option value="Other">
                                    Other
                                </option>

                                <option value="Personal">
                                    Personal
                                </option>

                                <option value="Sleep">
                                    Sleep
                                </option>

                                <option value="Social">
                                    Social
                                </option>

                                <option value="Study">
                                    Study
                                </option>

                                <option value="Work">
                                    Work
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="CloneRow1" class='clonedInput'>
                        <td>
                            <input class="input_hr" type="number" value="0" name="ID1_hour" id="ID1_hour" aria-labeledby="hourLabel" min="0">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="input_min" type="number" value="0" name="ID1_min" id="ID1_min" min="0" max="59" aria-labeledby="minuteLabel">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="input_act" type="text" name="ID1_act" id="ID1_act" aria-labeledby="activityLabel">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="input_cat" name="ID1_cat" id="ID1_cat" aria-labeledby="cateogryLabel">
                                <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disbled">
                                    Select Category
                                </option>

                                <option value="Class">
                                    Class
                                </option>

                                <option value="Entertainment">
                                    Entertainment
                                </option>

                                <option value="Exercise">
                                    Exercise
                                </option>

                                <option value="Extracurricular">
                                    Extracurricular
                                </option>

                                <option value="Family">
                                    Family
                                </option>

                                <option value="Meal">
                                    Meal
                                </option>

                                <option value="Other">
                                    Other
                                </option>

                                <option value="Personal">
                                    Personal
                                </option>

                                <option value="Sleep">
                                    Sleep
                                </option>

                                <option value="Social">
                                    Social
                                </option>

                                <option value="Study">
                                    Study
                                </option>

                                <option value="Work">
                                    Work
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class='output'>
                        <th>Total:</th>
                        <td id='output' colspan='3'></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div id="addDelButtons">
               <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add section" class='fontawesome-plus' aria-label="Add Row"> 
                <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="remove section above" class='fontawesome-minus' aria-label="Remove Last Row">
                <input type="button" id="btnRes" value="Reset form" aria-label="Reset Form">
                <input type="button" id="btnCalc" value="Calculate" aria-label="Reset Form">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <p id='demo'></p>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the JS

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var num     = $('.clonedInput').length, // Checks to see how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            newNum  = new Number(num + 1),      // The numeric ID of the new input field being added, increasing by 1 each time
            newElem = $('#CloneRow' + num).clone().attr({'id': 'CloneRow' + newNum}).addClass('addedRow').fadeIn('slow'); // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value

    /*  This is where we manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new, cloned element
        Below are examples of what forms elements you can clone, but not the only ones.
        There are 2 basic structures below: one for an H2, and one for form elements.
        To make more, you can copy the one for form elements and simply update the classes for its label and input.
        Keep in mind that the .val() method is what clears the element when it gets cloned. Radio and checkboxes need .val([]) instead of .val('').
    */
        // Title - select
        newElem.find('.input_hr').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_hour').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_hour').val('0');

        // First name - text
        newElem.find('.input_min').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_min').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_min').val('0');

        // Last name - text
        newElem.find('.input_act').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_act').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_act').val('');

        // Color - checkbox
        newElem.find('.input_cat').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_cat').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_cat').val('');

    // Insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
        $('#CloneRow' + num).after(newElem);
        $('#ID' + newNum + '_title').focus();

    // Enable the "remove" button. This only shows once you have a duplicated section.
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);

    // Right now you can only add 13 sections, for a total of 15. Change '13' below to the max number of sections you want to allow.
        if (newNum == 13)
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "That's all, folks!"); // value here updates the text in the 'add' button when the limit is reached 
    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function () {
    // Confirmation dialog box. Works on all desktop browsers and iPhone.
        if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to remove this section? This cannot be undone."))
            {
                var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
                // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                $('#CloneRow' + num).slideUp('slow', function () {$(this).remove();
                // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
                    if (num -1 === 1)
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
                // enable the "add" button
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "add section");});
            }
        return false; // Removes the last section you added
    });
    // Enable the "add" button
    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
    // Disable the "remove" button
    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
    // Reset the entire form
    $('#btnRes').click( function () {
    {
    // Confirmation dialog box. Works on all desktop browsers and iPhone.
        if (confirm("Do you really want to reset the form? All data will be lost."))
            {
                 document.getElementById("BudgetFormEng").reset();
                 $('.addedRow').remove();
                 $('#output').empty();
             };
        return false;
    };});

    $('#btnCalc').click(function() {
        var hours = $(".input_hr").serializeArray();
        var minutes = $(".input_min").serializeArray();
        var categories = $(".input_cat").serializeArray();
        var blargh  = [];
        for(var i=0;i<categories.length;i++){
           blargh.push({cat:categories[i].value,hour:hours[i].value,minute:minutes[i].value});//add object literal
        }

       /* jQuery.each(blargh, function (i, cat) {
            console.log(i.value)
        });

       /* var totalHours = 0;
        var totalMins = 0;

        jQuery.each(hours, function( i, hours) {
            totalHours += parseInt(hours.value) * 60
        });

        jQuery.each(minutes, function( i, minutes) {
            totalMins += parseInt(minutes.value) 
        });

        var totalTime = totalHours + totalMins;
        var realMin = totalTime % 60;
        var realHour = Math.floor(totalTime / 60);

        $('#output').empty();
        $('#output').append(realHour + ' hours, ' + realMin + ' minutes');*/

    })
});
```

Comment: What are you getting from the `console.log(i.value)`?

Comment: sorry. thats code i was just messing around with. i will edit it out.

Comment: WHat is the question and where are you having problems?

Comment: My next step is for when a user clicks calculate, it will open up a modal with all of the inputs listed out. I guess im just more looking for advice on how to accomplish this.  Do I need to have the inputs saved into an object and then run a for loop through the object?

Comment: @AndrewLevy Do you know how to create a modal?

Comment: only way to calculate is by looping the data which can be looping rows in DOM or binding to other objects and looping those

Answer (score 1):

First: You'll save yourself MUCH time and work, if you use classes instead of id for your elements.

This solution works only, if you give your TR a class of `trclass`, your activity a class of "input_act" and the category a class of "input_cat"

I output the categories and activities on the console only, decide yourself what to do with it.

the actual calculating is rather easy:

```
$(function() {
      $("#btnCalc").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        calcIt();
      });
}

function calcIt() {
var hours = 0;
var minutes = 0;
var activities = "";
var cats = "";
  $(".trclass").each(function(index) {
  hours += parseInt($(this).children("td").children(".input_hr").val()); 
  minutes += parseInt($(this).children("td").children(".input_min").val());   
  activities += $(this).children("td").children(".input_act").val();   
  cats += $(this).children("td").children(".input_cat").val();   
  });
$("#output").html(hours+":"+minutes);
console.log(activities);
console.log(cats);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/os214gru/2/)